# How to check if a previously selected media file exists?

Tags: android

I let users select a sound that I get like this:

```
String sound = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI)
                  .toString();
```

And I store it in shared preferences. How do I later make absolutely sure that sound is still available on the device? It's returned as

> content://media/external/audio/media/219

or

> content://media/internal/audio/media/34

or it might be on an SD card or whatever. I need to check that it exists so that I can have it already selected the next time I show the ringtone picker. If the file turns out not to exist, the ringtone picker will crash.

I've tried checking like this

```
File file = new File(URI.create(sound).getPath()); 
if (file.exists()) {
     //this is never true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this helper class [UriHelpers.getFileForUri()](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/UriHelpers.java) to create file as

`File file = UriHelpers.getFileForUri(sound)`

Update 1: You can just use [FileUtils.java](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java) `getPath()` method which has check for api level.